# Try downloading images with zeros using wget

Tags: bash

When I run the following command in linux:

```
wget http://page.com/{0000..0100}.jpg
```

he tries to download the following sequence:

> http://page.com/0.jpg
>
> http://page.com/1.jpg
>
> http://page.com/2.jpg
>
> http://page.com/3.jpg
>
> ...
>
> http://page.com/100.jpg

that is, it does not place the zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider upgrading Bash. Your code works on Bash4+:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION {001..003}
4.4.19(1)-release 001 002 003
```

but not on older versions like Bash 3.x:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION {001..003}
3.2.57(1)-release 1 2 3
```

If you're unable to upgrade, you can use `printf` as a workaround:

```
wget $(printf "http://page.com/%04d.jpg\n" {1..100})
```

Answer (score 1):

The bash expansion isn't going to pad teh numbers to use mathematically insignificant zeros.  You can use `seq` with the `-w` (width) option to pad with leading zeros.

```
for i in `seq -w 1 1000`
do 
  wget http://example.com/path/to/$i.jpg
done
```